`flutter build web` is not creating `flutter_bootstrap.js`
When I do:
% cd my_app
% flutter create .
% flutter build web
% ls -l build/web

total 2340
drwxrwxr-x 6 sir sir    4096 Jun 20 00:59 assets
drwxrwxr-x 3 sir sir    4096 Jun 20 00:59 canvaskit
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sir sir     917 Jun 20 10:00 favicon.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sir sir    3891 Jun 20 09:59 flutter.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sir sir   11109 Jun 20 10:00 flutter_service_worker.js
drwxrwxr-x 2 sir sir    4096 Jun 20 00:59 icons
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sir sir     958 Jun 20 10:00 index.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sir sir 2347393 Jun 20 10:00 main.dart.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sir sir     911 Jun 20 10:00 manifest.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sir sir      90 Jun 20 10:00 version.json
% ls -l build/web/flutter_bootstrap.js
*** not found
% grep boot build/web/index.html 
<script src="flutter_bootstrap.js" async></script>

... and so the app fails when deployed because flutter_bootstrap.js can't be found
flutter_bootstrap.js is sometimes created. However I can't figure out why its sometimes there and sometimes not.
Related to:
`flutter build web` is not creating a new build?

You can try this method to regenerate the web configurations for your Flutter project

Delete the Web Folder
Recreate Web Configurations using flutter create --platforms web .
Run flutter clean and flutter build web

By following these steps, you should be able to regenerate the web configurations and resolve any issues related to missing files like flutter_bootstrap.js.
